# Array addressing in AT&T GAS assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I'm building a compiler for a subset of C, and now I'm dealing with arrays. Suppose I have the following:

```
int main() {
    int x[3];
    x[0] = 1;
    x[1] = 3;
    x[2] = 4;
}
```

In assembly, the asignments would be like this:

```
movl    $1, -12(%ebp)
movl    $3, -8(%ebp)
movl    $4, -4(%ebp)
```

So far, so good. Now if I wanted to access an arbitrary position, stored in `%ebx`, how should I do it? I've been reading [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax#Address_operand_syntax) but I don't quite get the syntax.

I've tried the following but it does not seem to work:

```
# Suppose I want to do x[1] = 5
movl $1, %ebx

movl $5, -4(%ebp, %ebx, 4)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *base* of the array is not `-4(%ebp)` but `-12(%ebp)` (as that's where the first item is placed) so the indexing should be like this:

```
movl $1, %ebx
movl $5, -12(%ebp, %ebx, 4)
```